# R - Import & Merge Multiple Excel Files And Add Filesource Variable

Tags: r, excel, import, merge, import-from-excel

I have used R for various things over the past year but due to the number of packages and functions available, I am still sadly a beginner. I believe R would allow me to do what I want to do with minimal code, but I am struggling.

#### What I want to do:

I have roughly a hundred different excel files containing data on students. Each excel file represents a different school but contains the same variables. I need to:

> 1. Import the data into R from Excel
> 2. Add a variable to each file containing the filename
> 3. Merge all of the data *(add observations/rows - do not need to match on variables)*

I will need to do this for multiple sets of data, so I am trying to make this as simple and easy to replicate as possible.

#### What the Data Look Like:

> **Row 1**    Title
>   **Row 2**    *StudentID    Var1    Var2             Var3      Var4        Var5*
>   **Row 3**    11234           1          9/8/2011      343      159-167      32
>   **Row 4**    11235           2         9/16/2011    112      152-160      12
>   **Row 5**    11236           1         9/8/2011      325      164-171      44

Row 1 is meaningless and Row 2 contains the variable names. The files have different numbers of rows.

#### What I have so far:

At first I simply tried to import data from excel. Using the XLSX package, this works nicely:

```
dat <- read.xlsx2("FILENAME.xlsx", sheetIndex=1, 
                  sheetName=NULL, startRow=2, 
                  endRow=NULL, as.data.frame=TRUE, 
                  header=TRUE)
```

Next, I focused on figuring out how to merge the files (also thought this is where I should add the filename variable to the datafiles). This is where I got stuck.

```
setwd("FILE_PATH_TO_EXCEL_DIRECTORY")
filenames <- list.files(pattern=".xls")
do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, read.xlsx2, sheetIndex=1, colIndex=6, header=TRUE, startrow=2, FILENAMEVAR=filenames));
```

I set my directory, make a list of all the excel file names in the folder, and then try to merge them in one statement using the a variable for the filenames.

When I do this I get the following error:

> Error in data.frame(res, ...) : 
>    arguments imply differing number of rows: 616, 1, 5

I know there is a problem with my application of lapply - the startrow is not being recognized as an option and the FILENAMEVAR is trying to merge the list of 5 sample filenames as opposed to adding a column containing the filename.

#### What next?

If anyone can refer me to a useful resource or function, critique what I have so far, or point me in a new direction, it would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: In your command `do.call("rbind", lapply(...` you have misspelled `startrow`. It should be `startRow`.

Comment: Your call currently gives the filenamevar all the file names in filenames each read.xlsx is called within `lapply`. If you run `lapply(filenames, function(x) read.xlsx2( sheetIndex=1, colIndex=6, header=TRUE, startrow=2, FILENAMEVAR=x)))` Does it work?

Comment: bdemarest - good catch on startrow.  Mnel - when I run that I get the following error: Error in path.expand(file) : argument "file" is missing, with no default

Comment: With 2 minor changes, @mnel's command works for me: `lapply(filenames, function(x) read.xlsx2(file=x, sheetIndex=1, colIndex=6, header=TRUE, startRow=2, FILENAMEVAR=x))`

Comment: @bdemarest - When I try it with your changes, I get the following---> `Error: unexpected ';' in "do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, function(x) read.xlsx2(file=x, sheetIndex=1, colIndex=6, header=TRUE, startRow=2, FILENAMEVAR=x));"`--------> Here's my code, can you see an easy mistake? : `do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, function(x) read.xlsx2(file=x, sheetIndex=1, colIndex=6, header=TRUE, startRow=2, FILENAMEVAR=x));`

Comment: You are missing `)` at the end of the command. `;` is unneeded, but is not really an error.

Comment: @bdemarest - My head is stuck in SAS. Thanks.

Comment: does `startRow=2` contain `header`? And what does `colIndex=6` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll post my comment (with bdemerast picking up on the typo). The solution was untested as `xlsx` will not run happily on my machine

You need to pass a single `FILENAMEVAR` to `read.xlsx2`.

```
lapply(filenames, function(x) read.xlsx2(file=x, sheetIndex=1, colIndex=6, header=TRUE, startRow=2, FILENAMEVAR=x))
```

Comment: This works great, the only addition to the code would be the final step of merging the datasets into one matrix so that they can be output back to excel.

Comment: You have the code for merging `do.call('rbind', lapply(...))`!

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to clarify because I know I (as a beginner) would be a little lost if I was trying to follow. Thanks!